# How to stop receiving spam email from server

Tags: linux, centos

I have CentOS and the hosting provider provided me `Plesk Control Panel`.

We used to have a problem that website was sending loads of spam emails.

It was new joomla installed and it has vulnerabilities we tried to fix it but wasn't easy I tried to install 'Parallels Premium Outbound Antispam' by clicking 'Install' in plesk panel it started installation but at some point stopped with an error, can't remember what it was but started sending emails with info about it.

Here is the content of email that I get:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at `mail.thecanvasprintstudio.co.uk`.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<drweb@mail.thecanvasprintstudio.co.uk>:
Unable to forward message: mail server permanently rejected message (#5.3.0).

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Return-Path: <anonymous@mail.MYDOMAIN.co.uk>
Received: (qmail 1501 invoked by uid 100); 23 Jun 2016 10:00:07 +0100
Date: 23 Jun 2016 10:00:07 +0100
Message-ID: <20160623090007.1497.qmail@mail.MYDOMAIN.co.uk>
From: root@mail.MYDOMAIN.co.uk (Cron Daemon)
To: drweb@mail.MYDOMAIN.co.uk
Subject: Cron <drweb@mail> /opt/drweb/update.pl
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/var/drweb>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=drweb>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=drweb>

Dr.Web (R) update details:
Update server: http://update.msk.drweb.com/unix/500
Update has begun at Thu Jun 23 10:00:01 2016
Update has finished at Thu Jun 23 10:00:07 2016

Following files has been updated:
 /var/drweb/bases/drwtoday.vdb
 /var/drweb/bases/dwntoday.vdb
 /var/drweb/bases/dwrtoday.vdb
 /var/drweb/updates/timestamp
```

How to stop sending me this emails or spam or notifications?
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Rob's answer is right. Those mails are apparently sent by the software that you installed. You need to fix the installation. Sadly, you don't provide enough information to pinpoint the problem exactly, especially information about the failed installation of that anti-spam plugin.

Comment: That's correct. Because since I have installed the 'Parallels Premium Outbound Antispam' I am receiving emails. SO far I got like 2000 mails. Which is very annoying

Comment: The sample mail is a bounce (mail rejection) due to incomplete configuration. It seems that the software wants to regularly send update information to a mail account"drweb" which doesn't exist on your server. You need to fix the config so that it sends the mails to an existing address. However, even if you do that, it will send these regular mails that you consider spam...

Comment: Do a search for "dr web cron emails every hour" for some guidance.

Comment: Thank you mate. With your help I have found the solution. I have posted how to stop Drweb emails

Answer (score 1):

Stop Those Irritating Dr. Web Antivirus Cron Update Emails on Plesk 11.5+

After recently updating our server, we started receiving some irritating cron emails from the DrWeb daemon. One every hour to be exact, that’s twenty-four every day, agh! Here is a simple way to turn it off.
Log in as root to your server via SSH and open /etc/drweb/drweb32.ini. Search for

‘CronSummary’ around line 297:

```
CronSummary = yes
```

And replace with:

```
CronSummary = no
```

Once you’ve made the change do a restart for the Dr. Web daemon:

```
/etc/init.d/drwebd restart
```

All done! No more irritating update emails.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting what you received. That isn't spam sent to you but a response to (possible) spam sent to them from someone who claimed to be you. It's called "bounceback".

What happens is, the spammer doesn't want to get auto rejected by someone's anti-spam service, so they put in the return email address other people's addresses. Then, if it gets rejected, they don't have to deal with it but at least it will get through to a majority of users.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Hi Thanks Rob. So there is no way that I can stop server sending mail? Some how not to receive this mails any more

Comment: Again, you are not sending the original email and it has nothing to do with you. You can block the sender who responded in your example but that does you no good cause they're not the one causing you the problem. It's just an issue you have to live with caused by bad people.